# Check the existence of an object in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I found this code in response to another question:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSUInteger count = [managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:request error:&error];
[request release];

if (!error){
  return count;
}
else
  return 0;
```

The problem is, I don't know what to make my fetch request be, in order to have it only potentially return my object, and no others.

Comment: Please note that the error handling here is incorrect; [as is generally the case in Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH204-SW1), you must check the direct return value (`count`) before checking the error object. In this case, [the docs say](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html) that a return of `NSNotFound` signals an error.

Comment: What do you mean by "my object? You have to create an NSPredicate to determine your fetch criteria.

Comment: You should provide the Entity name and the attributes you are interested in for us to help you)

Comment: You should put more code, regarding to the type of object you want to retrieve, etc.

Comment: Andrew: Seriously, you are member on stackoverflow for more than 15 month now. In that time you've asks ~300 questions on objc/cocoa/iOS. And still you just copy&paste code from other post, trough it into your post and than expect us to fill in the rest. I really don't feel motivated to help you with that attitude. I am sure others will have the same feeling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request is an NSFetchRequest.  You create one, and use it to find your object.  For example...

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Person"];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ssan = %@", ssan];
```

Now, you use that fetch request, and it will find all "Person" entities with attribute "sean" matching the string variable .

If you only want to find one object, you need some type of unique identifier to search on.